# Check if LatLong is inside a polygon

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, openlayers

i have got lat and lon of a person ,i need to find this person is inside or outside of a particular polygon. since i am using KML vector overlay to show zone on the openlayers google map  .Please advice

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#poly

Answer (score 1):

```
In your init: function()

//Awesome design
style = { styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({ "temporary": style})};

//Make the layer        
this.selectLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("draw_polygon", style);

//Make the control
this.selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(this.selectLayer, OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon, {featureAdded: this.toggleDraw});

whatever.map.addControl(this.selectControl);

Then:

toggleDraw: function(feature) {
//Do some magic with finding if the uses is inside (example) search_options.viewModel.searchForPerson(feature);
}
```

I'm afraid I cannot give you full code, but you get the idea.